# Weka how to predict new unseen Instance using Java Code?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I wrote a WEKA java code to train 4 classifiers. I saved the classifiers models and want to use them to predict new unseen instances (think about it as someone who wants to test whether a tweet is positive or negative).

I used *StringToWordsVector* filter on the training data. And to avoid the "*Src and Dest differ in # of attributes*" error I used the following code to train the filter using the trained data before applying the filter on the new instance to try and predict whether a new instance is positive or negative. And I just can't get it right.

```
Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("models/myModel.model"); //reading one of the trained classifiers


    BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("Tweets/tone1.ARFF"); //read training data

    Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

    Filter filter = new StringToWordVector(50);//keep 50 words
    filter.setInputFormat(data);
    Instances filteredData = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);

    // rebuild classifier
    cls.buildClassifier(filteredData);


    String testInstance= "Text that I want to use as an unseen instance and predict whether it's positive or negative";
    System.out.println(">create test instance"); 
    FastVector attributes = new FastVector(2); 
    attributes.addElement(new Attribute("text", (FastVector) null)); 


    // Add class attribute. 
    FastVector classValues = new FastVector(2); 
    classValues.addElement("Negative"); 
    classValues.addElement("Positive"); 

    attributes.addElement(new Attribute("Tone", classValues)); 
    // Create dataset with initial capacity of 100, and set index of class. 
    Instances tests = new Instances("test istance", attributes, 100); 
    tests.setClassIndex(tests.numAttributes() - 1); 

    Instance test = new Instance(2); 
    // Set value for message attribute 
    Attribute messageAtt = tests.attribute("text"); 
    test.setValue(messageAtt, messageAtt.addStringValue(testInstance)); 

    test.setDataset(tests); 

    Filter filter2 = new StringToWordVector(50);
    filter2.setInputFormat(tests);
    Instances filteredTests = Filter.useFilter(tests, filter2);

    System.out.println(">train Test filter using training data"); 
    Standardize sfilter = new Standardize(); //Match the number of attributes between src and dest.
    sfilter.setInputFormat(filteredData);  // initializing the filter with training set 
    filteredTests = Filter.useFilter(filteredData, sfilter);    // create new test set

ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver(); //save test data to ARFF file
saver.setInstances(filteredTests); 
        File unseenFile = new File ("Tweets/unseen.ARFF");
        saver.setFile(unseenFile); 
        saver.writeBatch();
```

When I try to Standardize the Input data using the filtered training data I get a new ARFF file (unseen.ARFF) but with 2000 (same number of training data) instances where most of the values are negative. I don't understand why or how to remove those instances.

```
    System.out.println(">Evaluation"); //without the following 2 lines I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.
    filteredData.setClassIndex(filteredData.numAttributes() - 1);
    filteredTests.setClassIndex(filteredTests.numAttributes() - 1);

    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(filteredData); 
    eval.evaluateModel(cls, filteredTests); 
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
```

Printing the evaluation results I want to see for example a percentage of how positive or negative this instance is but instead I get the following. I also want to see 1 instance instead of 2000. Any help on how to do this will be great.

```
> Results
======

Correlation coefficient                  0.0285
Mean absolute error                      0.8765
Root mean squared error                  1.2185
Relative absolute error                409.4123 %
Root relative squared error            121.8754 %
Total Number of Instances             2000
```

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand why you load a classifier and then you train it again....

Comment: Also, you have two different stringtowordvector filters: they will generate two different sets of attributes. The code works, but I think it makes no sense. You should apply the same filter to the testset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reached a good solution and here I share my code with you. This trains a classifier using WEKA Java code then use it to predict new unseen instances. Some parts - like paths - are hardcoded but you can easily modify the method to take parameters.

```
/**
* This method performs classification of unseen instance. 
* It starts by training a model using a selection of classifiers then classifiy new unlabled instances.
*/

    public static void predict() throws Exception {
        //start by providing the paths for your training and testing ARFF files make sure both files have the same structure and the exact classes in the header

        //initialise classifier
        Classifier classifier = null;

        System.out.println("read training arff");

        Instances train = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Train.arff")));
        train.setClassIndex(0);//in my case the class was the first attribute thus zero otherwise it's the number of attributes -1

        System.out.println("read testing arff");
        Instances unlabeled = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.arff")));
        unlabeled.setClassIndex(0);

        // training using a collection of classifiers (NaiveBayes, SMO (AKA SVM), KNN and Decision trees.)
        String[] algorithms = {"nb","smo","knn","j48"};
        for(int w=0; w<algorithms.length;w++){
            if(algorithms[w].equals("nb"))
            classifier = new NaiveBayes();
            if(algorithms[w].equals("smo"))
            classifier = new SMO();
            if(algorithms[w].equals("knn"))
            classifier = new IBk();
            if(algorithms[w].equals("j48"))
            classifier = new J48();

        System.out.println("==========================================================================");
        System.out.println("training using " + algorithms[w] + " classifier");

        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
        //perform 10 fold cross validation
        eval.crossValidateModel(classifier, train, 10, new Random(1));
        String output = eval.toSummaryString();
        System.out.println(output);

        String classDetails = eval.toClassDetailsString();
        System.out.println(classDetails);

        classifier.buildClassifier(train);
        }

        Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);

        // label instances (use the trained classifier to classify new unseen instances)
        for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) {
            double clsLabel = classifier.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
            labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
            System.out.println(clsLabel + " -> " + unlabeled.classAttribute().value((int) clsLabel));
        }

            //save the model for future use
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myModel.dat"));
            out.writeObject(classifier);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("===== Saved model =====");

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `eval.predictions()`. It is an `java.util.ArrayList<Prediction>`. Then you can use Prediction.weight() method to get how much positive or negative your test variable is....

Comment: eval.predictions() outputs null. Is that normal or am I doing something wrong? Could you put this in an example please?

Comment: Are you using  eval.predictions()  after invoking eval.evaluateModel(cls, filteredTests)?

Comment: Yes, but either way the output is null

Comment: Then try 'cls.ClassifyInstance'  for classifying the instance

Comment: I did this now `Instance newInst = testDataset.instance(0);` `double pred = cls.classifyInstance(newInst);` and pred value = 1.0.

Comment: `cls.classifyInstance(newInst)` returns the prediction result for `newInst` as a double, starting from 0. If it returned 1.0, it means it is predicted to belong to the second class. `eval.predictions()` returns the prediction result too, but if you test the classifier on a testset it will return the results for each instance

Answer (score 1):

`cls.distributionForInstance(newInst)` returns the probability distribution for an instance. Check the [docs](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html#distributionForInstance(weka.core.Instance))